# Getting a 401 Error with Github API and Apollo Client Yet It previously worked

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql

I had successfully queried a list of Github issues from a flutter repository using Github Graphql API and Apollo and was able to fetch them to my application. Strangely, I woke up this morning with a HTTP 401 Error, I am unable to understand where the error is coming from and how to catch and correct it.

```
2021-03-29 07:51:53.590 2532-3799/smartherd.githubissuetracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
    Process: smartherd.githubissuetracker, PID: 2532
    com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 401 
        at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.parse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:108)
        at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor$1.onResponse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:53)
        at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloServerInterceptor$executeHttpCall$1.onResponse(ApolloServerInterceptor.kt:110)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The Request

```
val token = "MyToKenHere"
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
        val original: Request = chain.request()
        val builder: Request.Builder =
            original.newBuilder().method(original.method(), original.body())
        builder.header("Authorization", "bearer $token")
        chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
    .build()
val apolloClient: ApolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
    .serverUrl("https://api.github.com/graphql")
    .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
    .build()

val results = apolloClient.query(LoadgitQuery()).await()
val theget = results.data?.organization?.repository?.issues?.nodes

arrayList_details.clear()

theget?.forEachIndexed { index, value ->

}
```

Comment: 401 means unauthorized so you have to check token

Comment: Test with a query like https://api.github.com/user which should validate your token simply from the command line with a client like curl

Answer (score 1):

```
 val apolloClient= ApolloClient.Builder()
        .serverUrl("YourDamin")
        .addHttpHeader("Accept","application/json")
       
        .addHttpHeader(AUTHORIZATION, token!!)
        .build()


    lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {

        try {
            val response = apolloClient.query(UserQuery()).execute()
            if (response.hasErrors()) {

            } else {
              // response==>
            }

        }catch (e:com.apollographql.apollo3.exception.ApolloHttpException){

            try {
                if (e.statusCode == 401) {
                  // true
                }
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }
```

use this code for apollo3

Answer (score 0):

As @Rajasekaran M suggested, I checked and turned out I had to create a new token.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that sometimes you may (mistakenly) publish sensitive info like GitHub token to some repo. I know, it is a silly mistake but sometimes it happens for all of us.
And from what I noticed, as soon as GitHub sees that you published the token (not sure how it is checked though) it becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = apolloClient.query(AddressesQuery(page)).execute()
            //this lien add and get statusCode in catch
            response.dataOrThrow() 
            
            if (response.hasErrors()) {
                Constants.toastShort(context, response.errors!![0].message)
            } else {
            
                

               
            }
        } catch (e: ApolloHttpException) {
            Constants.apolloError(e, context)
        } catch (e: ApolloNetworkException) {
            Constants.toastCheckNetwork(context)
        }
    }
```